# ASP.Net View PDF

Tags: asp.net, pdf

Is it possible that when you have a webpage, when you open the PDF, the file view is defaulted to 100% size?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [Open Parameters](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/PDFOpenParameters.pdf) for Acrobat PDF.

```
 <a href="/path/to/doc.pdf#zoom=100">PDF Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Specifying PDF Open Parameters in a URL](http://www.heinelt.info/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=36&Itemid=52) has a few more examples of other behavior you can specify, and also links to the pdf that [tvanfosson references.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/809967/41153)