# HTTPResponse - browser zoom size

Tags: pdf, zooming

Is there a way to control the zoom size of the HTTPResponse with the contenttype ='application/pdf'?

Answer (score 3):

i try this it work.

`download.ashx?id=1&#zoom=100`

Answer (score 1):

See [PdfOpenParameters.pdf](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/PDFOpenParameters.pdf) for a larger list of options you can pass into the PDF viewer.

For example, `view=Fit` is a favorite of mine

[Specifying PDF Open Parameters in a URL](http://www.heinelt.info/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=36&Itemid=52) has a few more examples, and also links to the pdf I cite above.

---

See Also: [SO:ASP.Net View PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809913/asp-net-view-pdf)